# Socket bind fails even after using SO_REUSEADDR with IPv6

Tags: c, network-programming

My application needs to bind a socket on the same port with the same IPv6 address. I am using the code below to achieve the same. However second bind throws an error 'Address already in use'.
BTW, i get this error only if I include the listen call for the first socket. Without the listen call, the second socket binds just fine.

What I am doing wrong? Please help me understand.

Thanks

```
int fd1 = ::socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (fd1 < 0)
{
    perror("fd1 socket()");
    return -1;
}

// Set SO_REUSEADDR for both sockets
int reuse = 1;
if (fcntl(fd1, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) <0)
{
    perror("fd1 fcntl64 failed");
    return -1;
}
if (::setsockopt(fd1, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0)
{
    perror("fd1 SO_REUSEADDR failed");
    return -1;
}
if (::setsockopt(fd1, SOL_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, &reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0)
{
    perror("fd1 SO_REUSEADDR failed");
    return -1;
}


sockaddr_storage storage;
socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(storage);
memset(&storage, 0, addrlen);
sockaddr_in6& addr = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6&>(storage);
addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
addr.sin6_port = 143;
addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
sockaddr* pAddr = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&storage);

int val = 2;
socklen_t len = sizeof(val);

if (::getsockopt(fd1, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &val, &len) < 0)
{
    perror("fd1 getsock failed");
    return -1;
}

printf("Getsockopt returned %d at %d\n",val, __LINE__);

if (::bind(fd1, pAddr, sizeof(sockaddr_in6)) < 0)
{
    perror("bind fd1 failed");
    return -1;
}

if (::getsockopt(fd1, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &val, &len) < 0)
{
    perror("fd1 getsock failed");
    return -1;
}

printf("Getsockopt returned %d at %d\n",val, __LINE__);
if (listen(fd1, 128) < 0)
{
    perror("fd1, listen");
        return -1;
}
if (::getsockopt(fd1, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &val, &len) < 0)
{
    perror("fd1 getsock failed");
    return -1;
}

printf("Getsockopt returned %d at %d\n",val, __LINE__);
// Get the local address for fd1
addrlen = sizeof(storage);
if (::getsockname(fd1, pAddr, &addrlen))
{
    perror("getsockname for fd1 failed");
    return -1;
}
char straddr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
if (!inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &addr.sin6_addr, straddr, sizeof(straddr)))
{
    perror("inet_ntop for fd1 failed");
    return -1;
}
printf("fd1=%d addr=%s:%d\n", fd1, straddr, addr.sin6_port);

addrlen = sizeof(storage);
addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
addr.sin6_port = 143;
int fd2 = ::socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (fd2 < 0)
{
    perror("fd2 socket()");
    return -1;
}
if (::setsockopt(fd2, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0)
{
    perror("fd2 SO_REUSEADDR failed");
    return -1;
}
if (::setsockopt(fd2, SOL_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, &reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0)
{
    perror("fd1 SO_REUSEADDR failed");
    return -1;
}

if (::bind(fd2, pAddr, sizeof(sockaddr_in6)) < 0)
{
    perror("bind fd2 failed");
    return -1;
}

// Get the local address for fd2
if (::getsockname(fd2, pAddr, &addrlen))
{
    perror("getsockname for fd2 failed");
    return -1;
}
if (!inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &addr.sin6_addr, straddr, sizeof(straddr)))
{
    perror("inet_ntop for fd2 failed");
    return -1;
}
printf("fd2=%d addr=%s:%d\n", fd2, straddr, addr.sin6_port);

return 0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `socket(7)` man page:

> `SO_REUSEADDR` - Indicates  that  the  rules  used  in validating  addresses supplied in a `bind(2)` call should allow reuse of local addresses.  For `AF_INET` sockets this means that a socket may bind, *except when there is an active listening socket bound to the address.  When the listening socket is bound to `INADDR_ANY` with a specific port then it is not possible to bind to this port for any local address*. Argument is an integer boolean flag.

(emphasis mine)

Your first socket is bound to port 143 on the IPv6 equivalent of `INADDR_ANY`, then it's put in listening state. Thus no other socket could be bound on port 143 as long as the first socket remains open.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looks like I should read the man pages more carefully!

Comment: Then, what is the use of `SO_REUSEADDR` on Linux, when you cannot actually reuse any address with it?

Comment: @Lingxi, sockets remain semi-opened in state `TIME_WAIT` for a certain amount of time after being closed. That e.g. could result in server applications not being able to start right after they were shut down, because their old listening socket is still around. In that case, `SO_REUSEADDR` allows the new socket to bind to the same address as the old one. It exposes for a moment the new server instance to receiving data from the old connections - very unlikely, but still possible, hence the option to explicitly allow reuse.